# Facing an error while making delegated approver field read only

Tags: trigger, user

I want to make delegated approver un editable for a profile users.
Since we cannot use Delegated Approver field in the validation rule, I have implemented a trigger. Here I am facing the below error message wen saving the code. Can some one suggest, how can i fix this.

Trigger:

```
trigger usertrigger on User (before insert, before update) {

    Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
    String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;

        for( User u : Trigger.newMap.keySet() )
            {
                if(ProfileName ==  'Contract Manager')
                    {
                        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(u).DelegatedApprover != Trigger.newMap.get(u).DelegatedApprover)
                              {
                                    apexpages.addmessages('You cannot update the delegated approver, please contact administrator');
                              }
                    }
            }
}
```

Error message:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(User) from the type Map at line 9 column 21

Answer (score 2):

It's better to retrieve `oldUser` separately rather than referencing it in `if` block. Also the method signature of `Map` is `void get(User.Id)`. You need to send `Id` of user in order to get that `User`. Example: `Trigger.oldMap.get(u.Id).DelegatedApproverId`. However I recommend to get user first and then use it.

Refer below code:

```
trigger usertrigger on User (before insert, before update) {

    Id profileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
    String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;

    for( User u : Trigger.new ) {
        if(ProfileName ==  'Contract Manager') {
            User oldUser = Trigger.oldMap.get(u.Id);
            if(oldUser.DelegatedApproverId != u.DelegatedApproverId ) {

                u.addError('You cannot update the delegated approver, please contact administrator');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since `DelegatedApprover` API name is not available to use it directly, Thanks to @Venky to finding workaround that `DelegatedApproverId` can be used instead.